# 'Trying to get property of non-object' after using array_unshift

Tags: php, arrays

I have an object :

```
$data = '[{"NO":"1","ID_JPS":"AAA"},{"NO":"2","ID_JPS":"BBB"}]';
$data_ori = json_decode($data);
```

I am getting the `NO` and `ID_JPS` properties within a `for` loop.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($data_ori); $i++){
   echo $id_item = "NO = " . $data_ori[$i]->NO . " & ID_JPS = " . $data_ori[$i]->ID_JPS;
}
```

I'd like to insert a blank data into `$data_ori` so I use `array_unshift()`:

```
$data_blank = array( 'NO' => 'NULL','ID_JPS' => 'NULL');
array_unshift($data_ori,$data_blank);
```

But, after doing that, my `for` loop stops working. The error message is:

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object.

How do I get the data from the inserted item?

Comment: is `$count` intentional?

Comment: ups... I'll edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're inserting an array, not an object. Easiest is just to [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) it:

```
$data_blank = (object)array( 'NO' => 'NULL','ID_JPS' => 'NULL');
```